# Select specific data after defined decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a column that contains version information in a format like:

```
20.6.4.4200
10.28.30.2678
22.8.34.1200
```

I’m wanting to only select the values after the last decimal like:

```
4200
2678
1200
```

What is the best way to do this or is a Regex needed?

Comment: String functrions are highly vendor-specific. Please tag your question with the database you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server...?

Comment: You might use reverse and charindex to find the position of the final “.” inside a substr() from start to len() minus that position (maybe with a + or - 1 in there, I used this method before but don’t have my code handy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, that has poor regex support, you can use string functions as follows:

```
right(val, charindex('.', reverse(val)) - 1)
```

The idea is to get the position of the last dot in the string, counting from the end of the string, then extract the relevant part of the string with `right()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5f0b09b3fb3074a42c312c8132dcf82)**:

```
select val, right(val, charindex('.', reverse(val)) - 1) new_val
from (values('20.6.4.4200'), ('10.28.30.2678'), ('22.8.34.1200')) t(val)
GO
```

```
val           | new_val
:------------ | :------
20.6.4.4200   | 4200   
10.28.30.2678 | 2678   
22.8.34.1200  | 1200
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is probably the simplest method.  Databases that support regular expressions usually support something that retrieves a substring.  The syntax would be like:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]+$')
```

Of course, the function might have a different name.